# mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die('Error establishing connection')

Tags: php, database-connection, boolean-logic

I know when this statement is executed, it first check i.e. mysqli_connect is successful then another die statement is not executed.
What I want to know here is that if the first check i.e. mysqli_connect is successful, does it mean that it is same as boolean true? and if the mysqli_connect is unsuccessful, does it mean that it is same as boolean false??

Comment: Instead of asking question first try to read manual:- [mysqli::__construct](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

Comment: okay thank you.. i will read manual ... I was watching tutorial and this confusion bugged me so much... @alive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the manual [mysqli::__construct](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

> ***Return Values***: Returns an object which represents the connection to a MySQL Server.

So it will return a databases connection object when connection happen successfully.

If not then `or` condition will execute with the message you wrote in it which is :- *Error establishing connection*

For a better practice always try to find what problem occur while connection, so that you can fix it. So write like below:-

```
mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
```

Reference:- [mysqli_connect_error()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php)

Comment: Thank you for help @alive to die
When database connection object is returned, can we say it is boolean true (1)... The thing I was confused was if database connection is not returned and error is produced, does it mean boolean false (0)

Comment: `When database connection object is returned, can we say it is boolean true `-> No. if database connection is not returned and error is produced, does it mean boolean false ->No, it will return an error object with error number and message, you need to check that [what  mysqli_connect_error() is going to do]

Comment: Thanks for the help @Alive to Die

Answer (score 1):

The statement is returning an object, not any boolean values. Try to store it in a variable and var_dump to see what it's returning. It **Returns an object representing the connection to the MySQL server**.

[image]

In the case of not successful, the or statement will execute and halt the execute due to die()

Comment: You can simply give him manual link instead of answering. [BTW i am not a down-voter at all]. You can check:- [mysqli::__construct](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

Comment: @catcon No, its an object

Answer (score 0):

I think mysqli_connect_error() will help you fixing this problem.

It return a string which describes the error.

https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.connect-error.php